# How can I hide gmail inbox menu when user loads via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api

Please, I need help.

I'm trying to create a google chrome extension that hides the google inbox menu automatically when a gmail user loads gmail.

I have basic understanding of javascript and chrome extension api.

Where the problem is in accessing the API.

Comment: You need a content script.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail now supports toggle of this Main menu by clicking the burger menu on the left. However I don't like this solution mainly because I can't bind it to any shortcut.

[image]

This is my solution of toggle gmail sidebar using [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) chrome extension. Toggle is binded to the Escape button. The same can be done on init, without listening for the keydown event for example `$(".nH.oy8Mbf.nn.aeN").fadeOut();` or `$(".nH.oy8Mbf.nn.aeN").hide();`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Toggle left sidebar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Toggles left gmail sidebar on "esc" keypress.
// @author       blaz.krizaj@gmail.com
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @match        *://mail.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (27 == e.keyCode) {
            var leftSideBar = $(".nH.oy8Mbf.nn.aeN");
            if (leftSideBar.css('display') == 'none') {
                leftSideBar.fadeIn();
            }
            else {
                leftSideBar.fadeOut();
            }
        }
    });
});
```